# is group chat for facebook implemented in the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat

I know that the feature for user to user chat is implemented in the API, but I was wondering if they implemented the ability to access the group chat (the chat you can have with your facebook group) has been implemented.

I don't see anything about it in the doc, so I was wondering if any one here would know. If it is possible to create apps that utilizes group chat, can some one point me in the right direction (doc for it, etc.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was answered by one of the Facebook staff on January 18th in the [Facebook XMPP Developer Relations](https://www.facebook.com/groups/315869928431057/) group:

"[Multi user chat] is not currently on the XMPP roadmap, but definitely belongs on the wishlist."

This goes for both arbitrary friend chats and chats defined by members of a Facebook group.

Comment: Any news about group chat?

Comment: I am no longer in this group, but feel free to join it :)

Comment: If Multi User Chat is not supported in XMPP. What is alternate way of implementing the group chat in Android? @Kustard

Comment: @Roster I didn't do any Android dev work, but take a look at asmack (if you haven't already) https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack