# XMPP Multi User Chat

Tags: xmpp, chat, facebook-chat

Hi using XMPP I have integrated with Facebook's Chat. I would like to know though if messages sent from a mutli user chat (MUC) in Facebook can also be handled? or is this client dependent?

I am using JsJac and at the moment any messages sent from a MUC are lost are never recieved by my app, any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

See this - [is group chat for facebook implemented in the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7563763/1163175) . i try make MUC for my chat app, but i suggest that in this time this service unavailable yet in public using.