# Facebook Group chat in Android App

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am new to Android and i am trying for below concept and let me know anyone how to achieve this one.
I am log in using facebook in my app and after i need to start fb group chat from there. is it possible and how? Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you gone through the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)? any effort so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be clear that you should use [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/) for using FB related services in your android application.

Facebook group chat is currently not available in facebook SDK. See this post:
[is group chat for facebook implemented in the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563763/is-group-chat-for-facebook-implemented-in-the-api)

So you can use facebook for logging in and implement the chatting system yourself by creating backend server. This would be difficult obviously that using the SDK.

Good Luck!